# Adhesion issues using AmazonBasics PLA

Tags: filament, pla, troubleshooting, creality-ender-3, adhesion

I am a neophyte at 3D printing. My Ender 3 is now 4 days old and I modified it out of the box with a glass bed.  My first print was a fairly complex item, but a mere 90 x 160 x 3.5 mm. Used the sample filament that was included with the 3, first print was a keeper.

Today I was trying to use the [AmazonBasics PLA 3D printer filament](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DVLQSN3).  I am not amused. I'm using the identical setup and glass bed as before but poor adhesion prevented a print.

I cleaned the glass with acetone followed with 90 % IPA...  No joy.  Another cleaning using a dishwashing detergent and IPA, boo hiss!

The glass bed is a Creality for the Ender, purchased separately For the first print, no adhesive was used, just the glass (cleaned the glass prior to the first print as described).

Your suggestions are solicited.

Comment: Coat the bed with sevaral layers of Elmers white glue, or gluestick.

Comment: Out of the box ender-3 does not have a glass bed. at least mine doesn't have one. Did you swap it? Do you use some adhesive?

Comment: More information is found [here](/a/7840/), [here](/a/6049/), [here](/a/8344/), [here](/a/8034/) and [here](/a/6861/).

Comment: I used AmazonBasics PLA filament for a print and wasn't too impressed with it. I was able to get it to print, but the quality of the print wasn't up to par with other PLA filaments I'd used in the past. I realize different colors of filament have different print qualities and you have to tune your printer each time you change a color or manufacturer, but really, the print was mediocre at best. Previous prints were of much better quality. The only reason I used the AmazonBasics PLA was because it was a specific color. I doubt I'll go back to it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: If you fixed it, post an answer, the fix should not be in the question, this is not a forum. Besides, printing on a raft is not really a solution when you have such a great upgrade like a glass slate. An adhesive on the glass is usually the way to go, but if you are happy, we are happy :) p.s. I did not know you could clean with beer

Comment: @R.Ogburn The fact that you have modified the machine is relevant. It opens a huge can of worms, starting with an unleveled bed (very common) and no adhesive (somewhat needed on glass for PLA, very common) to electrical problems (like bad connection, somewhat uncommon). in my experience, the rough buildTak-clone surface is easier to start out with as a neophyte. Glass beds can get flatter bottoms though. Raft is not commonly needed for PLA.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer taken from OP's question*

---

****Fixed it!****

Reset bed height to clear nozzle by 0.04 mm. Printed on raft.  I appreciate the answers.

Comment: @R.Ogburn - If you care to submit your own actual answer, I will delete this Wiki answer, thanks.